# Is there way to fix websocket issue for production?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, amazon-ec2, nestjs

I tried with the below nginx configuration for production but socket is not working . When I configure the same for staging then staging socket is working fine.

Can someone help me on this ?

NGINX Configuration:

```
upstream api {
  server client:5001;
}

upstream client {
    server client:8001;
}


server {
listen              443 ssl;
listen              [::]:443 ssl;
server_name  __;


 location / {
  proxy_pass http://api;  
  proxy_redirect default;
  proxy_buffers 8 1024k;
  proxy_buffer_size 1024k;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  proxy_set_header Host            $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $proxy_protocol_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
  # Very important, controls proxied websocket connection timeout
  proxy_read_timeout 600s;
 }

 location /apiwebsocket/ {
            proxy_pass http://client;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy false;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_read_timeout      86400s;
            proxy_connect_timeout 86400s;
            proxy_send_timeout 86400s;
            send_timeout 86400s;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
}
```

**Client side:**

`const newSocket: any = io("domain:8001", {path:"/apiwebsocket",port:8001,transports:["websocket"]}); newSocket?.on("connect", () => { console.log("Connection Successful"); });`